# What is the official way to host dart / flutter package in enterprise (private) environment?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Since the package [pub_server](https://pub.dev/packages/pub_server) is discontinued. But get recommended for that use case in the [README.md from pub-dev](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev)

So I'm a bit confused about what is now the recommended way.

I know about the package [unpub](https://pub.dev/packages/unpub) but it doesn't feel right to use it in an environment.

Is there something official from the dart team which is not discontinued?

Answer (score 2):

You can use internal private pub server.
Flutter team use the same for Internal private packages and plugins.

[image: private pub server]

https://pub.dev/packages/unpub

To use this server you have to install mongodb.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/